# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/WORLD

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, gradle

I'm trying out Gradle and JDBC for the first time. I have the following gradle.build file:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.36'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

In my HelloMySQL.java file, I'm trying to establish a connection to the MySQL database `WORLD`(Verified the URL and port). I have the following code:

```
package Hello;
import java.sql.*;

public class HelloMySQL {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        try{
            System.out.println("Trying to connect...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/WORLD", "root", "root");
            System.out.println("Creating statement...");
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                String sql;
                sql = "SELECT * FROM City LIMIT 10";
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                while(rs.next()){
                  int id = rs.getInt("id");
                  String name = rs.getString("name");
                  String countryCode = rs.getString("CountryCode");
                  System.out.println(id + " " + name + "\t " + countryCode);
                }

        } catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

I've also tried adding this line before the `DriverManager.getConnection`:

```
Class.forName('com.mysql.jdbc.Driver');
```

but it throws a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`
Am I doing something wrong with the gradle build file?

EDIT: I have not added the jar for MySQL connector to the project. Gradle will download it for me, right?

Comment: @anant666 It was boilerplate code generated by eclipse. I forgot to remove it from the code I pasted here.

Comment: How are you **running** it? The driver needs to be on the runtime classpath.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I'm new to Java. I'm running it using Eclipse's _Run_. I've tried cleaning the project after every change I make to the build file. I also tried changing the dependency type from `compile` to `runtime`.

Comment: I've never used Gradle from Eclipse, so I don't know how it interacts. As Eclipse doesn't use Gradle by default: did you actually create it as a gradle project?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes I created it as a gradle project. Do you know how I can compile and run using gradle CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Not exactly a problem but still posting it for people who might struggle with Eclipse.

After you make changes to the `gradle.build` file, Cleaning the project won't do. You'll need to refresh the gradle project as well.

Right click in the build.gradle file -> Gradle -> Refresh Gradle Project